# How to handle designing issue of cassandra table output used into another cassandra table input?

Tags: cassandra, nosql, cassandra-3.0

Have two table as below :

```
CREATE TABLE model_vals (
    model_id int,
    data_item_code text,
    date date,
    data_item text,
        pre_cal1 text,
    pre_cal2 text,
        pre_cal3 text,
    pre_cal4 text,
        pre_cal5 text,
    pre_cal6 text,
    PRIMARY KEY (( model_id, data_item ), date)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY ( date DESC )


CREATE TABLE prapre_calulated_vals (
    id int,
    precal_code text,
    date date,
    precal_item text,
    pre_cal1 text,
    pre_cal2 text,
    pre_cal3 text,
    pre_cal4 text,
    pre_cal5 text,
    pre_cal6 text,
    PRIMARY KEY (( id, precal_item ), date)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY ( date DESC )
```

After processing input data from Kafka , using spark-sql,  the result data is inserted into first (model_vals)  C* table. Which further serve some web-service end points.

Another business logic need  data from above first(model_vals) C* table, process it an populate restuls in second (prapre_calulated_vals) C* table.

For web-service endpoint , end-user can pass require where condition and get the data from first(model_vals) C* table.

But further processing I need to read the entire first(model_vals) C* table,
process the data , do other set of calculation and populate second (prapre_calulated_vals) C* table.

First(model_vals) C* table has million of records , so we cant load the entire table at a time to process ..

How to handle this scenario in C* ? What alternatives I have to handle this situation ?

Answer (score 1):

You have several options depending on the complexity of what you need done. In general it sounds like you need some sort of streaming framework that simultaneously with writing new data to your records, also does some business logic and writes to a second table.

Some technologies that come to mind are,

1. Spark Streaming
2. Flink
3. Apex

All of these technologies have connectors for Cassandra that enable reading both entire tables as well as portions of tables in efficient manners for doing joins with new data. Of course this will be slower than aggregation techniques on flat files or doing smaller requests of tiny amounts of data.

If you don't need a streaming approach, since you are already using Spark, I would suggest using a subsequent SparkSQL query to populate your final table.

Comment: thank you Russel , as always you been prompt and helpful. Yeah as I said already me using spark sql. but how to map C* partition with spark partitions , any sample or blog regarding it ?

Comment: Mapping Cassandra and spark partitions is generally not important, this level of detail is handled under the hood by the spark Cassandra connector. Maybe you can ask another more specific question?